# Buttons in a scroll view not working

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I have created a scroll view in Unity, and wanted to make the elements inside clickable. It would function as a level select menu. The level panels are instantiated from a prefab.

As a first approach I added an `IPointerClickHandler` to the parent object (the background of the prefab, in grey)

[image: the level prefab]

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ScrollViewItem : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI title, length;

    public void initialize(string titleInit, float lengthInit)
    {
        title.text = titleInit;
        length.text = "Length: " + lengthInit.ToString("F0") + "s";
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("hello");
    }
}
```

It worked fine until yesterday, and today my Unity editor crashed because of CPU issues I assume, and now this does not work anymore. For some reason the `IPointerClickHandler` does not react at all, and also if I add a `Button` to the prefab, the `Button` stops working as well.

I don't know if it is helpful, but the hierarchy is built as following:

-canvas
--background
---content
----here the panels are instantiated

Comment: Can you check if you have an EventSystem in your scene, and that it's configured correctly? It's possible it might have been deleted from your scene or corrupted by whatever caused the crash, or something just before.

Comment: I have an event system added but just the standart one. I'm not quite into this event stuff yet because i am new to coding with unity.

Comment: Does your text have raycast target enabled? If they are children of the parent, its possible they are blocking the interactions. 

Else, does a button component function at all?

Comment: Button does function, but not if it is instantiated from this ecact prefab. Other prefabs work fine for some reason... I can also click on the grey where there is no text and it still does not work. I assume that this is happening because of the scroll view.

Comment: Check all panels in the hierarchy bottom from your item with IPointerClickHandler. Disable all of them and check if click works. If works mean they blocked click.